# How to count number of rows, Json

Tags: php, mysql, json

How to count number of rows, where my id is located in one of the fileds and that field is json object:

```
{
  "Monday":{"1":"15","2":"27","3":"74","4":"47","5":"42","6":"53"},
  "Tuesday":{"1":"11","2":"28","3":"68","4":"48","5":"43","6":"82"},
  "Wednesday":{"1":"13","2":"29","3":"69","4":"49","5":"44","6":"54"},
  "Thursday":{"1":"14","2":"30","3":"70","4":"50","5":"45","6":"55"},
  "Friday":[]
}


$getMenus = $db->next_record($db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as total, product_menu_meals FROM product_menus WHERE 1"));

$getMeals = (json_decode($getMenus['product_menu_meals'], true));
if(in_array($mainMeal['meal_id'], array_filter($getMeals['Monday'])) ||
in_array($mainMeal['meal_id'], array_filter($getMeals['Tuesday'])) ||
in_array($mainMeal['meal_id'], array_filter($getMeals['Wednesday'])) ||
in_array($mainMeal['meal_id'], array_filter($getMeals['Thursday'])) ||
in_array($mainMeal['meal_id'], array_filter($getMeals['Friday']))){echo $getMenus['total'];};
```

Example my id = 15 and I can see that in first group Monday I can see 15, this mean that there is 1 row with that value. Now I have 200 rows and only in 150 rows I have id = 15 so I would like to count and display number 150

---

```
>  <?php 
>                     $getMenus = $db->next_record($db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as total, product_menu_meals FROM product_menus WHERE 1"));
>                     
>                     $getMeals = (json_decode($getMenus['product_menu_meals'], true));
>                     
>                     if(in_array($mainMeal['meal_id'], array_filter($getMeals['Monday'])) ||
>                     in_array($mainMeal['meal_id'], array_filter($getMeals['Tuesday'])) ||
>                     in_array($mainMeal['meal_id'], array_filter($getMeals['Wednesday'])) ||
>                     in_array($mainMeal['meal_id'], array_filter($getMeals['Thursday'])) ||
>                     in_array($mainMeal['meal_id'], array_filter($getMeals['Friday']))){echo $getMenus['total'];}; 
>                   ?> Menus
```

Comment: Can you please explain it little bit more or would be great if you can post more code, I mean from where you get this sting etc

Comment: I have got table in MySQL with fields, 1 of the fields got json object  listed above for each row. Now I would like to count number of rows that's got let say number 15 in the json object

Comment: seems to be difficult one :) is Postgress is easy but not in MySQL !

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
                        $MenusArray = array();
                        $arrayMenus = array();

                        $codeQuery = $db->query("SELECT * FROM product_menus;");
                        $codeQuery2 = "SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM product_menus WHERE";
                        $i = 0;
                        while($followingdata = $db->next_record($codeQuery)){

                        $arrayMenus[] = (json_decode($followingdata['product_menu_meals'], true));

                         if(in_array($mainMeal['meal_id'], array_filter($arrayMenus[$i]['Monday']))){$codeQuery2 .= " product_menu_id = '".$followingdata['product_menu_id']."' OR";}
                         if(in_array($mainMeal['meal_id'], array_filter($arrayMenus[$i]['Tuesday']))){$codeQuery2 .= " product_menu_id = '".$followingdata['product_menu_id']."' OR";}
                         if(in_array($mainMeal['meal_id'], array_filter($arrayMenus[$i]['Wednesday']))){$codeQuery2 .= " product_menu_id = '".$followingdata['product_menu_id']."' OR";}
                         if(in_array($mainMeal['meal_id'], array_filter($arrayMenus[$i]['Thursday']))){$codeQuery2 .= " product_menu_id = '".$followingdata['product_menu_id']."' OR";}
                         if(in_array($mainMeal['meal_id'], array_filter($arrayMenus[$i]['Friday']))){$codeQuery2 .= " product_menu_id = '".$followingdata['product_menu_id']."' OR";}

                        $i++;
                        }
                        $codeQuery2 = substr($codeQuery2,0,-2); 

                        $queryMenus = $db->next_record($db->query($codeQuery2));

                        echo  $queryMenus['total'];

?> Menus
```